# How to remove Windows and partition on dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

If I have a copy of the latest Ubuntu installer on DVD can I run it from within Ubuntu or simply boot from it and then be given the option to remove windows and the partition so I have just Ubuntu on my drive with no separate partition?  I'm trying to get rid of windows and the partition.  I'm currently running a dual boot, Ubuntu/windows system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use an Ubuntu DVD to remove it.

Start off by booting off the disk and enter live CD mode. Once inside, start up the partition manager (like Gparted). Find your Windows partition in Gparted's menu—it'll be listed as an NTFS drive.
Right-click on that Windows partition and choose "Delete" from the menu. Your machine may have other Windows-related partitions as well, like "System Reserved" and recovery partitions. If you want, you can delete these as well (but make sure you have recovery discs handy if you're going to delete a recovery partition).
Right-click on your Linux partition and choose "Resize/Move." Resize it so it takes up the rest of the now-free space on your drive.
Click the "Apply All Operations" button in the toolbar to perform the selected tasks. It may give you a warning saying that your computer may not boot, but with most Linux instalations this shouldn't be a problem (though if it is, [check out this article to fix it](http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual&lang=C#gparted-fix-grub-boot-problem)). This process may take some time, so let it be!
When it finishes, you should have a hard drive with nothing but Linux on it. Your boot menu will still have some Windows entries, and it'll work fine if you leave them there, but if you want to clean things up, just open up a Terminal in Linux and run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

to remove them.

Here goes the [original source](http://lifehacker.com/how-to-uninstall-windows-or-linux-after-dual-booting-508710422). :)

I've done this myself, but usually I just wipe my whole hard drive rather than just deleting a partition.